# UserControl inBetween TabHeader and Tab Content

Tags: wpf

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible or not...

But what I'm trying is to put a `UserControl` in between the `TabHeader` and `TabContent`, but I am not able to put the Margin as much as I want.

This is a `Styler` which i applied on my all `Tab-Control`

```
 <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Content.DataContext.HeaderInfo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="TabItemRoot" Margin="10,0,5,0">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="10,5,0,5" x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        <Border x:Name="border" Height="Auto" Padding="0,0,0,0" Opacity="0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#A3FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Whenever I set the Margin it moves the Content in it but not the control.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to define the ControlTemplate for the TabControl, not only for the items with something like this:

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabControl">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="Green" Width="100" Height="100" />
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Style>
```

**edit:**
I still don't really get what you want to do, but to place anything between the TabHeader and the TabContent, you could come up with something like this as the Template for the TabItems:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Row="0" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Usercontrol goes here</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where exactly do you want to insert the usercontrol?

Comment: in between `Tab-head` and `Tab-Content`.